# Is there any way to show a variable using decimal precision in Qweb?

Tags: odoo, odoo-11, qweb

I am showing a float variable in a Qweb report:

```
<t-set="my_qweb_float_variable" t-value="4.0"/>
<span t-esc="'%.4f'% my_qweb_float_variable"/>
```

I want to round it with the decimal precision of *Product Price*. I am rounding it to 4 digits because I know that *Product Price* has a decimal precision of 4 digits, but the right way would be to get the precision value from the record stored in the `decimal_precision` table, just in case users change it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Means, you have to print "my_qweb_float_variable" variable value like "4.0000". Am I Right?

Comment: Yes, but only if *Unit Price* decimal precision value is 4, if it was 2 I must print 4.00.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get `decimal_precision` table value this way:

```
<t t-set="decimal_precision" t-value="request.env['decimal.precision'].precision_get('Product Price')"/>
```

Then when you print the value of `decimal_precision` variable, it will show the browsable object of `decimal.precision` model.

And then you can get your field value this way:

```
<t t-esc="my_qweb_float_variable" t-options='{"widget": "float", "precision": decimal_precision}'/>
```

I hope this will helps you. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It need integer number for `precision` value otherwise it will fail.

Following is a example of 2 decimal precision in QWEB report.

Correct:

```
<t t-esc="my_qweb_float_variable" t-options='{"widget": "float", "precision": 2}'/>
```

Wrong:

```
<t t-esc="my_qweb_float_variable" t-options='{"widget": "float", "precision": 2.0}'/>
```